# how to animate the move of a point from a position to another in a HighCharts scatterplot

Tags: animation, highcharts, scatter-plot

In a HighCharts scatterplot I want to move a point from its position to another one using a smooth animation.
For example, in the scatteplot defined in the following code ([jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kd8A9/) link):

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            xAxis: {
                min: -0.5,
                max: 5.5
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Scatter plot with regression line'
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'scatter',
                name: 'Observations',
                data: [[1, 1.5], [2.8, 3.5], [3.9, 4.2]],
                marker: {
                    radius: 4
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

I want to move the first point from (1,1.5) to (2,2). Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use `point.update`.
This accepts point options as parameter, so you can pass `x` and `y` values.

Take a look the following code:

```
chart.series[0].points[0].update({x: 2, y: 2});
```

Pass an object as the third parameter with your animation options, you can see the options on the refference section.

```
chart.series[0].points[0].update({x: 2, y: 2}, true, {duration: 500, easing: 'linear'});
```

*Reference*:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Point.update()
- [animation types](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.animation)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/SM33n/)

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to adjust the animation speed?